# Ввод данных в excel через Phpexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Ведомость</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 
    require('PHPExcel.php');
    require('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');


    $nameAdd =   $_POST['name'];
    $rostAdd =   $_POST['rost'];
    $vesAdd =    $_POST['ves'];
    $genderAdd = $_POST['gender'];

    if (isset($_POST['add'])) { 

        $objExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', '№')
                ->setCellValue('B1', 'ФИО')
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'Рост, см.')
                ->setCellValue('D1', 'Вес, кг.')
                ->setCellValue('E1', 'Пол');

        $objAdd = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('index.xls');
        foreach ($objAdd->getWorksheetIterator() as $sheetAdd) {
            $getHighestRowAdd = $sheetAdd->getHighestRow();

            for ($i=2; $i <= $getHighestRowAdd; $i++) { 

                $number =    $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();
                $name =      $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();
                $rost =      $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue();
                $ves =       $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$i)->getValue();
                $gender =    $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$i)->getValue();

                $Row += $i; 

                if ($getHighestRowAdd <= $Row) { 
                    $Row += 1;

                    $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                            ->setCellValue("A" . $Row, $getHighestRowAdd)        
                            ->setCellValue("B" . $Row, $nameAdd)
                            ->setCellValue("C" . $Row, $rostAdd)
                            ->setCellValue("D" . $Row, $vesAdd)
                            ->setCellValue("E" . $Row, $genderAdd);
                } else { 
                    $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                            ->setCellValue("A" . $getHighestRowAdd, $number)        
                            ->setCellValue("B" . $getHighestRowAdd, $name)
                            ->setCellValue("C" . $getHighestRowAdd, $rost)
                            ->setCellValue("D" . $getHighestRowAdd, $ves)
                            ->setCellValue("E" . $getHighestRowAdd, $gender);
                }

                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objExcel, 'Excel5');
                $objWriter->save('index.xls');

                $Row = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // if (isset($_POST['delet'])) {
    //     unset($_POST['payment']);
    // }
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>ФИО</p>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="name">
    <p>Рост, см</p>
    <input type="text" name="rost" class="rost">
    <p>Вес, кг</p>
    <input type="text" name="ves" class="ves">
    <p>gender</p>
    <input type="text" name="gender" class="gender"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" name="add" class="add">Добавить</button>
    <button><a href="index.php" class="link">Назад</a></button>
    <input type="submit" name="delet" value="Отчистить">
</form>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь сделать так, что бы в файл Excel добавлялись новые записи, не удаляя старые записи

Выше есть код и скрины файла с данными и файл после срабатывание скрипта

Comment: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ - новая либо взамен PHPExcel. У вас есть старые данные? Что мешает выводить все вместе, а не дописывать файл?

Comment: @DaemonHK Мне нужно в файл Excel, в котором уже есть данные, добавить новые, а когда я их добавляю старые удаляются

Comment: Тогда почему вы начинаете с $i=2?

Comment: @DaemonHK Я уже решил проблему, спасибо что хотели помочь. Цикл начинается с 2, потому что первая строка это название столбцов, а её заново выводить не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Вот как я исправил ошибку, если вдруг кому-нибудь понадобиться

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Ведомость</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //Подключение библиотеки Phpexcel
    require('PHPExcel.php');
    require('PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

    $nameAdd =   $_POST['name'];
    $rostAdd =   $_POST['rost'];
    $vesAdd =    $_POST['ves'];
    $genderAdd = $_POST['gender'];

    if (isset($_POST['add'])) { 

        $objExcel = new PHPExcel();

        $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A1', '№')
                ->setCellValue('B1', 'ФИО')
                ->setCellValue('C1', 'Рост, см.')
                ->setCellValue('D1', 'Вес, кг.')
                ->setCellValue('E1', 'Пол');

        $objAdd = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('index.xls');
        foreach ($objAdd->getWorksheetIterator() as $sheetAdd) {
            $getHighestRowAdd = $sheetAdd->getHighestRow();

            $for = $getHighestRowAdd + 1;

            for ($i=2; $i <= $for; $i++) { 

                $number =    $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(0,$i)->getValue();
                $name =      $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(1,$i)->getValue();
                $rost =      $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,$i)->getValue();
                $ves =       $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(3,$i)->getValue();
                $gender =    $sheetAdd->getCellByColumnAndRow(4,$i)->getValue();

                $Row += $i;     

                if ($for != $Row) { 

                    $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue("A" . $i, $number)        
                        ->setCellValue("B" . $i, $name)
                        ->setCellValue("C" . $i, $rost)
                        ->setCellValue("D" . $i, $ves)
                        ->setCellValue("E" . $i, $gender);
                } else { 
                    $objExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue("A" . $Row, $getHighestRowAdd)        
                        ->setCellValue("B" . $Row, $nameAdd)
                        ->setCellValue("C" . $Row, $rostAdd)
                        ->setCellValue("D" . $Row, $vesAdd)
                        ->setCellValue("E" . $Row, $genderAdd);
                }

                $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objExcel, 'Excel5');
                $objWriter->save('index.xls');

                $Row = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    // if (isset($_POST['delet'])) {
    //     unset($_POST['payment']);
    // }
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div>
        <p>ФИО</p>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="name">
    </div>
    
    <div>
        <p>Рост, см</p>
        <input type="text" name="rost" class="rost">
    </div>
   
    <div>
        <p>Вес, кг</p>
        <input type="text" name="ves" class="ves">
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>gender</p>
        <select name = "gender">
            <option value = "2PAC" selected>Выберите пол</option>
            <option value = "М">М</option>
            <option value = "Ж">Ж</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" name="add" class="add">Добавить</button>
    <button><a href="index.php" class="link">Назад</a></button>
    <input type="submit" name="delet" value="Отчистить">
</form>
<script src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```